# Handling an generated shapes in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a program that allows the user to free draw shapes inside a JPanel, the drawn shapes are stored in an array-list of a general type (a class that is the class the shape types extend). However I need to allow the user to interact with the shapes. Read: event handlers. Any idea how to work that one?

Current code of how I draw my shapes, although it's unrelated:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList <shape> shapes;
    public enum ShapeType{LINE,OVAL};
    public ShapeType shapeType;
    public shape currentShape;
    public Color currentColor=Color.BLACK;
    public DrawPanel(){
        shapes= new ArrayList<shape>();
        currentShape=null;
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
        addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int i=0;i<shapes.size();i++)
        {
            shapes.get(i).draw(g);

        }
        if(currentShape!=null)
        {
            currentShape.draw(g);
        }
    }
    public void clearDraw(){
        shapes.clear();
        repaint();
       }

    public void setToOval(){
        setShapeType(ShapeType.OVAL);
    }
    public void setToLine(){
        setShapeType(ShapeType.LINE);
    }
    public void setShapeType(ShapeType shape){
        shapeType=shape;
    }
    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener{
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
            if(shapeType!=null){
                switch(shapeType){
                case LINE:
                    currentShape = new line(event.getX(),event.getX(),event.getY(),event.getY(),currentColor);
                    break;
                case OVAL:{
                    currentShape=new oval(event.getX(),event.getX(),event.getY(),event.getY(),currentColor);
                }
                break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
            if(currentShape!=null)
            {
        currentShape.setMyColor(currentColor);
                currentShape.setX2(event.getX());
                currentShape.setY2(event.getY());
                shapes.add(currentShape);
                currentShape=null;
                validate();
                repaint();

            }
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
            if(currentShape!=null)
            {
                currentShape.setMyColor(currentColor);

                currentShape.setX2(event.getX());
                currentShape.setY2(event.getY());
                validate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
    public void setCurrentColor(Color color){

        this.currentColor=color;

    }

}
```

Comment: *"Any idea how to work that one out?"* a lot, but for better help sooner post your [mcve]

Comment: I updated the post with the code of how exactly do i draw the shapes and save them inside the jpanel, although i dont understand how providing the code is related to explaining the concept since the idea is quite generic.

Comment: And if you've taken the [tour] and read [ask] you would know that generic questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Let me have a look at the code and help you with it :)

Comment: Ah, i see. My bad then. Just to note this is merely the drawing panel class. Not the entire thing,

Comment: Please read the [mcve] link and try to provide something similar to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapes are elements which you just draw on your surface. You cannot directly handle events on them. An option is to handle mouse events in your JPanel, and iterate through your list of painted shapes. You can check if a shape is located at your current mouse location, and based on that result, set your currentShape variable to this shape (or set currentShape to NULL and consider that probably NO shape is selected in your other handlers...)

Comment: I see, didn't think of it that way. Thank you

Comment: @WhiteheartAwashreh: if you iterate through, do so *backwards*, so you hit the top-most shapes first (z-order). In the future, please post a valid MCVE with your question so that the question and answers can be more specific.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, apologies I don't typically ask questions here so not informed well on details.

Comment: @trashgod I don't see a shape related example at the link you are referring to.. the link is about components and their z-order?

Comment: @ChristophBimminger: the `GraphPanel` cited maintains a `List<Node>`, but a `List<Shape>` would be similar.